# Why does an instance of a derived class call a method from the base class?

Tags: c++

Please look at example 1 and example 2.
Example 1 differs from Example 2 only in the overridden method run() from ** class IA ** 
Question is written at the end.

Example 1:

```
#include <iostream>

class IA {
    public:
    void run() {
        print();
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << "IA::print() \n";
    }
};

class A : public IA {
    public:

    void print() {
        std::cout << "A:: \n";
    }
};

int main() {
    A a1;
    a1.run();

    A * ptr = new A;
    ptr->run();
}
```

This code prints:

IA::print()
IA::print()

Example 2:

```
#include <iostream>

class IA {
    public:
    void run() {
        print();
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << "IA::print() \n";
    }
};

class A : public IA {
    public:
    void run() {
        print();
    }

    void print() {
        std::cout << "A:: \n";
    }
};

int main() {
    A a1;
    a1.run();

    A * ptr = new A;
    ptr->run();
}
```

This code prints:

A:: 
A::

**Why does it print like that? What is the difference?**

Thanks.

Comment: *Why does it print like that? What is the difference?* -- An open-ended question. 
 So the question to you is what difficulties are you having in understanding the code you posted?  What did you expect the sample code to print?

Comment: The question title is poor, since only one example is calling a base class function. This boils down to needing to further study inheritance in C++.

Comment: The question refers to "the overridden method `run()`. There are no virtual functions, so there are no overriding functions and no overridden functions.

Answer (score 3):

You chose not to make `print` virtual.  That means no dynamic dispatch occurs.  At any point you call the method, the local type information is used to determine which one you call.

```
void run() {
    print();
}
```

so when you call a non-virtual `print`, whatever local `print` function that is seen from where `run` is written is called.

In `IA::run`, the only visible `print` is the `IA::print`.  So `IA::run` calls `IA::print`.

In `A::run` you can see both `IA::print` and `A::print`; but the second hides the first.  So `A::print` is called.

What the actual dynamic type of the object is does not matter, because you didn't ask for virtual dispatch.  You asked for the function to be picked using local, static type information.

---

You can ask for virtual dispatch:

```
class IA {
public:
  void run() {
    print();
  }

  virtual void print() {
    std::cout << "IA::print() \n";
  }
};
```

I added the keyword `virtual` to `print`.  And now the first version will call `A::` version of `print`.

Some languages make all methods implicitly virtual.  C++ does not, because there is some runtime overhead to virtual methods, and C++ tries not to make you pay for things you aren't using.

Answer (score 0):

In the first program the member function run is a function of the base class. Within the function the static type of the pointe `this` is `IA`. The function print is searched in the class IA according to the static type of `this`.

In the second program the class A has the both functions run and print. They hide the corresponding functions of the class IA. So they are called

From the C++ Standard (13.2 Member name lookup)

> 1 Member name lookup determines the meaning of a name (id-expression)
>   in a class scope (6.3.7). Name lookup can result in an ambiguity, in
>   which case the program is ill-formed. **For an id-expression, name
>   lookup begins in the class scope of this;** for a qualiﬁed-id, name
>   lookup begins in the scope of the nested-name-speciﬁer. Name lookup
>   takes place before access control (6.4, Clause 14).